# g++ fails to build custom TensorFlow GPU op on Windows (from installed binaries)

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I'm trying to compile a custom GPU op for TensorFlow on Windows 10 (build 17134), with TensorFlow installed with `pip3 -install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu` but I can't seem to be able to compile the .so library file to load later in my script.

I've prepared two sample files: an [add_one.cc file](https://gist.github.com/Sergio0694/150b7f4a36d12783aad7dd9892898307) with the op setup, and a [cuda_op_kernel.cu file](https://gist.github.com/Sergio0694/91e5ae7e7559ad4b2c748c2fa4856e7f) with the GPU kernel code and launcher.

Now, I've followed both [the official TensorFlow guide here](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op#shape_functions_in_c) as well as [this other guide](https://medium.com/@taxfromdk/writing-a-new-tensorflow-operation-including-c-cuda-forward-gradient-and-grad-check-3c46708351e7) and the other articles listed in this last one, but I still can't get my custom op to compile correctly.

In the official TensorFlow docs, there's a paragraph for building custom ops when TensorFlow is installed from the binaries and not from source (so that's my case). This is their script:

```
TF_CFLAGS=( $(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_compile_flags()))') )
TF_LFLAGS=( $(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags()))') )
g++ -std=c++11 -shared zero_out.cc -o zero_out.so -fPIC ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} ${TF_LFLAGS[@]} -O2
```

Now, of course that won't work on Windows as is, so here's what I tried (beware, custom build scripts and troubleshooting build issues are definitely not my strong suit):

1. Downloaded MinGW, which has the g++ compiler included (version 7.3.0) and added it to my system path.
2. Those `${TF_CFLAGS[@]}` commands are a Bash feature, which of course isn't available in cmd on Windows. So, I just executed those Python snippets manually beforehand, and kept the resulting strings with those additional compiler flags.
3. Prepared my full build command putting all those flags together and tried to execute it.

This is the resulting command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 add_one.cc -o add_one.so -fPIC -IC:\Users\Sergio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -LC:\Users\Sergio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow -ltensorflow_framework -O2
```

> Note, I've removed the `-` right before the input file name from the original script, as leaving that there just made g++ fail with a "unrecognized command line option '-add_one.cc'" message. Was that `-` put there for a specific reason I'm missing, and/or should I replace it with something else instead?

Now, executing the command above just throws a ton of errors, [here's the full output](https://gist.github.com/Sergio0694/1d8f32a06039d4c620241cc72ce64f78).

I'm at a loss here and I'm not sure on how to proceed from here. It might very well be that I'm just missing something to configure in the build script, but I can't figure it out. Thanks for your help!

**EDIT #1:** so, I've installed VS2017 Community, and tried two different approaches to build the desired .so library file (*spoiler: none worked*).

1. Tried to replace `g++` with `cpp` in the above build command. This successfully created the .so file (at least that's something) without any warnings/errors. *But*, when I tried to load that .so file with `tf.load_op_library`, an error window popped up saying something like "Invalid image - the .so file is not meant to be used on Windows or it contains an error". After reading a discussion on StackOverflow about TensorFlow on Windows using .dll files over .so files for custom op, I tried to compile a .dll file with this same script. Again, the .dll was built just fine, but TensorFlow reported the same error when trying to load the library.
2. Tried to use CMake and a CMake build script. [Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/Sergio0694/fc94fb14388ee4b7b92be6e33704e5b9), taken mostly from [here](https://github.com/taxfromdk/tensorflow_dense_op/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt). This *seems* to work correctly, as I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL3Oe.png), and CMakes creates [a bunch of files and VS projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P84pp.png). But, when I open the generated project with VS and try to build it, I get this error:

> nvcc fatal   : 32 bit compilation is only supported for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and earlier

It seems pretty self-explanatory, so I tried again by adding `-m64` to the compilation flags in the `CMakeLists.txt` CMake script (hoping it'd get carried over when calling nvcc), but I still get the same error. Also tried to set the VS build platform to x64, that didn't work either. Is there something else I need to do to make nvcc compile the GPU kernel in 64 bit mode?

**EDIT #2:** made some more progress. As for the x64 platform, I discovered that adding `-DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64` when calling CMake fixes the issue and calls the x64 compiler. I've also removed the check for the upper version of MSBuild from here:

> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\include\crt

At around line 133, the code was failing if the MSBuild version detected was above 1911, so that was broken too when using the latest version of VS2017.

I think I should be pretty close now, the code seems to be compiling using `MSBuild /p:Configuration=Release add_one.vcxproj`, but the overall process fails throwing a bunch of errors in the `MSVC\include\type_traits` file (?), See [a screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2F1A.png).

**EDIT #3:** I discovered that the issue with that file was caused by VS2017 not properly supporting CUDA 9.0, so I also installed VS2015 and used this command:

```
CMake CMakeLists.txt -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 -G "Visual Studio 14 2015"
```

After doing so, the nvcc error seems to be fixed. **But**, I still can't get the library to build properly. The first error I was getting was caused by the imports in the .cc file not being executed correctly. I figured it was some problem with the path being added automatically by CMake, so I fixed that by manually adding this line in the CMake file:

```
include_directories("C:/Program Files/Python36/lib/site-packages/tensorflow/include")
```

Even with this though, the build fails with this error:

> C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include\tensorflow/core/platform/default/mutex.h(25): fatal er
>   ror C1083: Can't open include file: 'nsync_cv.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\Sergi\Documents
>   \op\test\add_one.vcxproj]

I've tried looking for that "nsync_cv.h" in the whole tensorflow install folder, but it just isn't there. I'm not sure what else to try at this point.

**EDIT #4:** changed approach and tried to build the op using the TensorFlow sources. I followed the sample code given by guschmue, setup my environment (VS2015, Anaconda 3 4.1.1 and all the other tools suggested, though I had to use CUDA 9.0 as the 8.0 version just refused to install), followed the instructions and built TensorFlow. Then I tried to build the custom op, but now it fails with the following error:

> add_one.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "void __cdecl AddOneKernelLauncher(float const *,int,int,
>   int,int,float *)" (?AddOneKernelLauncher@@YAXPEBMHHHHPEAM@Z) non risolto nella funzione "public: virtual void __cdecl A
>   ddOneOpGPU::Compute(class tensorflow::OpKernelContext *)" (?Compute@AddOneOpGPU@@UEAAXPEAVOpKernelContext@tensorflow@@@
>   Z) [C:\Users\Sergio\Documents\GitHub\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\user_ops_gen_python.vcxproj]

Not sure about that, since the implementation of that function is in the .cu file that's in the user_op folder, and the file path is in the cmake file too. [Here's the full code](https://gist.github.com/Sergio0694/28a1e197e3f05e933286c0927c2f5752) for that cmake file, just in case.

Comment: Because you are on Windows, it is 99.9% likely that you need to use a supported version of the Visual Studio compiler, not gcc

Comment: @talonmies Hello, thank you for your answer! I've installed VS and made some progress, I've updated my question with new info and a new error I'm getting from inside VS when building the library.

Comment: You need to ensure you are compiling for a 64 bit target everywhere

Comment: @talonmies I tried adding `-m64` and it didn't solve the issue, same for setting the target platform in VS to x64. I also tried to use `OPTIONS -m64` in the `cuda_add_library` call in the CMake file, but then nvcc crashed saying "duplicate definition of 'machine' flag", even after removing the first -m64 flag from the CXX_FLAGS. I really have no clue on what I'm doing wrong with this specific issue.